# What LinkedLists in Collection interface are single or doubly?

Tags: java, collections, linked-list, singly-linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I very well understand the concept of SLL or DLL.
But which one of them are we using in Collection interface?

So far I have encountered LinkedList in interfaces List,Queue and Dequeue.

Is there any other? And what type of LinkedList are we using in these 3 interfaces?
How can I even know it?

Comment: It should be noted that Java's native linked list has some issues. There is no equivalent of C++ [std::list::splice](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice), which can be used to move nodes within a list or from one list to another by changing the node pointers without any allocations or deallocations of nodes. Java's iterators can't be shallow copied, an assignment just points another variable at the same instance of iterator. Adding or removing any nodes from a list will invalidate all iterators to that list (except for the iterator used to do the add or remove).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List, Queue and Dequeue are just interfaces which provide a contract to be satisfied by the implementation. It doesn't matter how the list is implemented (in fact it doesn't even have to be a list).

The first line of [LinkedList javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) states

> Doubly-linked list implementation of the List and Deque interfaces.

Comment: Thanks, I checked it. Wonder why I even learnt about a difference between single and doubly when it has doubly implementation. One more thing, it said: Operations that index into the list will traverse the list from the beginning or the end, whichever is closer to the specified index.Do you know how does LinkedList know which one is closer? In starts from start or end and has reference to just next/previous index. So it has no clue what value will he get in future pointers..

Comment: It knows how many elements are there in the list (size). Say a list has 10 elements and you ask for the element at index 3, then it would start from the head of the list. If you ask for the 8th element, it would traverse from the end (tail) of the list

Answer (score 0):

**All linked lists in java are doubly linked lists**

Arrays and array lists have a major disadvantage: Deleting an element from the middle of the array costs too much. Because all elements in the array after the deleted element must be moved to the front of the array. (The same goes for inserting an element into the array)

**And then Java deliver the solution:**
Java introduced a linked list to solve the problem. In the Java programming language, all linked lists are actually two-way linked, in which each node also stores a reference to the predecessor node.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained why this is the case or added links to references that back up this claim